# Nested Query giving 5000 error code in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Query throwing 5000 error code:

```
select `e`.* from e where _engViewType = 'lk' and
s.assets[0]._id= 'de1bf489-b086-48c8-bbe1-af9527f9ca12' and
s.assets[1]._id IN (select RAW e1.s.assets[0]._id from e as  e1 where 
e1._engViewType = 'LE' and e1.s.assets[1]._id = '39dac2f6-19a9-441f-b293-2e9e5cf3b6ed')
```

but when i executed inner query and use its result in outer query like that:

```
select `e`.* from e where _engViewType = 'lk' and
s.assets[0]._id= 'de1bf489-b086-48c8-bbe1-af9527f9ca12' and
s.assets[1]._id IN ['ty6-bf48-b086-48c8-bbe1-af9527f9ca12']
```

giving correct output with no error.

Comment: Which version of Couchbase Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your first query runs fine on the latest development version. Could you give it a try with the latest version of Couchbase? If it still doesn't work, get back to us about the version you are using and what OS you are running on.

Comment: It should have worked. Also try the following select e2.* from e AS e2 where e2._engViewType = 'lk' and
e2.s.assets[0]._id= 'de1bf489-b086-48c8-bbe1-af9527f9ca12' and
e2.s.assets[1]._id IN (select RAW e1.s.assets[0]._id from e as  e1 where
e1._engViewType = 'LE' and e1.s.assets[1]._id = '39dac2f6-19a9-441f-b293-2e9e5cf3b6ed');